# html contenteditable li: new line should be inside current li. Diff Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable ol with li chicldren. When I press enter, I want the new line to be INSIDE the current li. I do not want it to start a new numbered li. The following html acts as desired in Chrome, but not in IE9.

I have a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D8rUH/ (Put the cursor after a and press enter.)

```
<ol  contenteditable="true">
     <li>
          <div>a</div>
     </li>
     <li>
         <div>b</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The result of putting the cursor after "a" and pressing enter:

in Chrome:

```
1. a
   (cursor is on this line)
2. b
```

in IE9:

```
1. a
2.
   (cursor is on this line)
3. b
```

Is there a way to make them both act like Chrome, without resorting to js and moving the DOM elements around.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in IE9 and you will have to use JS for the rescue.

Comment: For me, that's the expected behaviour. In fact Firefox does the same as IE. If I want to add a new line I use SHIFT+ENTER. But how could I start a new `li` in Chrome?

Comment: I see your point. It does make more sense the IE way, it's just not what I need. My users won't know the difference between enter and shift-enter. I want 1 enter to be in the same li and 2 enters (=2 blank lines) to be a new li. I was going to js code the second part. I'll have to rethink it.

Comment: Just checked. Enter and shift-enter are standard in Google Docs and Word. So I will keep that behavior. I can fix the Chrome bug by removing the div inside the li.